# Tor traffic modify in my local server

Tags: onion-services

Sorry about my poor English.
I am a newbie in tor development and installed Test Onion Service on my local computer and tested it.(https://www.jamieweb.net/blog/onionv3-hidden-service/)
Using tor browser, when I input *******************************.onion in URL, Ubuntu's index page appears.
My goal is modify it's traffic on my local computer. so instead of Ubuntu's index page, display my own text on tor browser is what I want.
Is it possible and how? I am using "https://github.com/torproject/tor"
Thank you.

Comment: Now that you have an onion site pointing to a local web server, you just need to change the content that you're serving on that web server just like you would with any other non-onion website. For example if you've installed Apache on your machine, you can follow [Ubuntu's "getting started"](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible! even more - adopt the IPFS for all the static content you do have. Utilizing a NodeJS service worker you can even put the load ahead from the backend. I'll be presenting exactly this in CryptoZoom conference at 12th of November 2022. To change the starting page you just need to change your index.html file, but don't limit yourself to it: a WordPress or Drupal are working just fine for any dynamic content you need